# Styling ASP.NET MVC validation errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can ASP.NET MVC's validation errors be styled? Where?
I tried editing .input-validation-error class in Site.css but that didn't have any effect.

pom

Comment: Must have had issue when refreshing the page yesterday. Today .input-validation-error class does change the color of the input box with an error. However, changing border thickness doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you style up `.field-validation-error` then this will change the validation error text messages.

```
.field-validation-error{ color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

If you style up `.input-validation-error` then this will change the input style when there is a validation error.

```
.input-validation-error{ background: pink; border: 1px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are doing is correct, but the css gets cached which means you won't necessarilly see the changes you make.

Once you have edited the css file, press Ctrl + F5 from your browser to reload css.