# ASP.NET MVC5 textarea not outlined in red on validation error

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with Bootstrap, and have the following in a Razor view for a contact form...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {role = "form"})) {
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.theirname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.theirname, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your name"})
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.theirname, "You must enter your name")</div>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.theiremail)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.theiremail, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your email"})
  <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.theiremail, "You must enter your email address")</div>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message)
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter message", cols = 40, rows = 5})
  <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message, "You must enter a message")</div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="copytome" name="copytome" checked="@Model.copytome" /> <label for="copytome">Send me a copy of the message</label>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" /></div>
</div>
}
```

If the user clicks the submit button without filling in their name or email address, the validation message is displayed correctly, and the textboxes are outlined in red.

However, the textarea doesn't get outlined, although the validation message is shown...
[image]

Here is the generated HTML...

```
<form action="/Home/Contact" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="theirname">Your name</label>
<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Your name field is required." id="theirname" name="theirname" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text" value="" />
<div><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="theirname" data-valmsg-replace="false">You must enter your name</span></div>
<label for="theiremail">Your email</label>
<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Your email field is required." id="theiremail" name="theiremail" placeholder="Enter your email" type="text" value="" />
<div><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="theiremail" data-valmsg-replace="false">You must enter your email address</span></div>
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea class="input-validation-error form-control" cols="40" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Message field is required." id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter message" rows="5">
</textarea>
<div><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="message" data-valmsg-replace="false">You must enter a message</span></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="copytome" name="copytome" /> <label for="copytome">Send me a copy of the message</label>
<div><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" /></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Anyone any idea why the textarea isn't outlined in red?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Presumably bootstrap doesn't include a style rule for invalid textarea elements. You could fix it by adding the following to your stylesheet:

```
 textarea.input-validation-error {
      border-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Duh, stupid me! I just assumed that as Bootstrap included CSS for other elements, it would include it for this, and that there must have been something deeper going on. Turns out it was simply missing! Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're stupid at all for this assumption.  I've found there's a lot of cases where the MVC or Bootstrap teams missed basic things like this.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033485/styling-asp-net-mvc-validation-errors) is another cool working option, hope helps someone.

Comment: Make sure you CTRL-F5 to make sure the changes are not being picked up due to a cache depending on which browser you are using, or check the version of the CSS file that is being generated directly through the browser to make sure these styles are definitely present.